# JMX exporter & spark-on-k8s-operator

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes, jmx-exporter, spark-operator, google-spark-operator

I'm trying to submit a spark application using spark operator and to expose metrics using JMX exporter.
I'm using Spark 3.1.1 & spark operator v1beta2-1.3.3-3.1.1
Here is a snippet from the configuration.

```
monitoring:
    exposeDriverMetrics: true
    exposeExecutorMetrics: true
    prometheus:
      jmxExporterJar: "/opt/spark/jars/jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.11.0.jar"
      port: 8090
      configFile: "/opt/spark/work-dir/prometheus/prometheus.yaml"
  driver:
    cores: 1
    coreLimit: "1200m"
    memory: "2g"
    javaOptions: "-Dconfig.file=/opt/spark/work-dir/conf/application_app.conf -Dlog4j.configuration=file:///opt/spark/work-dir/log/log4j_app.properties"
    labels:
      version: 3.1.1
    serviceAccount: spark-jobs-spark
```

The application doesn't expose any metrics from the driver.
below you can find prometheus yaml:

```
# These come from the application driver if it's a streaming application
      # Example: default/streaming.driver.com.example.ClassName.StreamingMetrics.streaming.lastCompletedBatch_schedulingDelay
      - pattern: metrics<name=(\S+)\.(\S+)\.driver\.(\S+)\.StreamingMetrics\.streaming\.(\S+)><>Value
        name: spark_streaming_driver_$4
        labels:
          app_namespace: "$1"
          app_id: "$2"
      - pattern: metrics<name=(\S+)\.(\S+)\.spark.streaming.(\S+)\.(\S+)><>Value
        name: streaming_query
        labels:
          job: "$1"
          instance: "$2"
          query: "$3"
          name: "$4"
      # These come from the application driver if it's a structured streaming application
      # Example: default/streaming.driver.spark.streaming.QueryName.inputRate-total
      - pattern: metrics<name=(\S+)\.(\S+)\.driver\.spark\.streaming\.(\S+)\.(\S+)><>Value
        name: spark_structured_streaming_driver_$4
        labels:
          app_namespace: "$1"
          app_id: "$2"
          query_name: "$3"
      # These come from the application executors
      # Example: default/spark-pi.0.executor.threadpool.activeTasks
      - pattern: metrics<name=(\S+)\.(\S+)\.(\S+)\.executor\.(\S+)><>Value
        name: spark_executor_$4
        type: GAUGE
        labels:
          app_namespace: "$1"
          app_id: "$2"
          executor_id: "$3"
      # These come from the application driver
      # Example: default/spark-pi.driver.DAGScheduler.stage.failedStages
      - pattern: metrics<name=(\S+)\.(\S+)\.driver\.(BlockManager|DAGScheduler|jvm)\.(\S+)><>Value
        name: spark_driver_$3_$4
        type: GAUGE
        labels:
          app_namespace: "$1"
          app_id: "$2"
      # These come from the application driver
      # Emulate timers for DAGScheduler like messagePRocessingTime
      - pattern: metrics<name=(\S+)\.(\S+)\.driver\.DAGScheduler\.(.*)><>Count
        name: spark_driver_DAGScheduler_$3_count
        type: COUNTER
        labels:
```

NOTE: Here is an interesting part. If I'm using spark-shell with javaagent defined with jmx exporter I'm able to find the metrics but not from spark-submit. What am I missing?

I tried to run a jmx exporter with spark-shell inside the pod and it worked. I have no idea why it's not working from spark-submit.